# iOS Provisioning portal : Cannot download Certificates

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning, provisioning-profile

I have created a distribution and development certificate on IOS Provisioning Portal.I followed all the guidelines and uploaded the the CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest on Portal.File for both dev and dist certificat was accepted.

BUT now i cant seem to download the certificate.Status of both certificate says "Issued" but there is no "Download" or "Revoke" button.Nor is any expiration date showing.I have refreshed the screen many time but to no avail.

I have an individual account so ideally certificates should be created instantly.Any one faced this issue before? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thx

Comment: What do you see in the Xcode organizer?

Comment: Well nothing..fact is i cant download the certificate.Its just says issued and there are no download button in Ios Provisioning portal.

Comment: What was the solution? We're seeing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the owner of the developer account has to confirm the download.

edit: I confirm the statement above. Just checked it.

Comment: Sorry, what's the solution? We're seeing the same problem as the OP.

Comment: Owner of the developer account (admin) has to approve the action.
Maybe it's best if the admin gives you the privileges to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a mobile device, or if your browser is pretending to be a mobile device you won't see the download link.

For me, I was using Chrome and forgot that I had turned on a user-agent switcher when iPad testing, and thus could not work out why there was no download link.

Anyone reading this question, just make sure you haven't done something silly like I had ;)